# How Do I Make SQL Return Identical Data

Tags: sql

```
select id, bossid
from employees
where id in (22299, 22299)
```

This results in

```
id   |bossid
22299|20529
```

I'd like

```
id   |bossid
22299|20529
22299|20529
```

Is there a way to make the db return results like this?

Comment: Why exactly would you want this?

Comment: @Erik I need to find out the bossid for each id's event in the database. id 22299, for example, achieved 3 events. I'm researching issues having to do with achievements and to do that I need the boss id. To accompany the id. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you include the achievement-id in the query, you'll get all 3 records. Without something to make the returned value unique, you won't get multiple copies of the same row.

Comment: You're selecting from `employees`.  I presume you only have one employee with a given ID in the database so you only get one row.  If you want to look at the information on events, you need to have a query that refers to your events table & possibly do a join between events & employees.

Answer (score 0):

Use union as

```
select id, bossid
from employees
where id = 22299
UNION
select id, bossid
from employees
where id = 22299
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select id, bossid
from employees
where id in (22299)
union all
select id, bossid
from employees
where id in (22299);
```

Another uses `join` which might look like:

```
select e.id, e.bossid
from employees e join
     (select 22299 as id union all select 22299
     ) ids
     on e.id = ids.id;
```

Or, just use `cross join`:

```
select e.id, e.bossid
from employees e join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 
     ) ids;
```

Comment: How does this scale? I have over 300 individual ids I need sql to return bossids for.

Comment: Where do those ids come from?  If from a table, then just use `join`.  If not, then why do you care about duplicates?